# Can I delete a particular element from TensorArray with dynamic size?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create a custom model using TensorFlow. I am using `tf.TensorArray()` function with `dynamic_size=True`.

I am facing issue when I want to delete a particular element based on a if condition.

for example,

```
t_a = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,size=0,dynamic_size=True)
t_a.write(0,[0,23])
t_a.write(1,[1,67])
t_a.write(2,[3,0])
t_a.write(3,[4,9])
```

Output:

```
t_a.read(2)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[3., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Now, my application would require me to read the value of first element in each row, if true, I need to delete that element from the TensorArray.

To access the individual element I use `t_a.gather([indices])`.

Any suggestions or work around for this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the value by making `clear_after_read` as `True`. After reading element, clear that value.

**Sample working code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=True)
ta = ta.write(0, 10)
ta = ta.write(1, 20)
ta = ta.write(2, 30)
indices = 1
ta.read(indices)
ta.gather([indices])
```

**Output**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>
```